# Android HtmlTextview mess

Tags: discussion

There are 3 dozen questions about android html in textviews all linking to other versions and none is marked as duplicate.

Maybe we should choose one question and make the others duplicates of it? Or delete some entirely as they make searchablity worse, especially when they have no really new answers.

https://stackoverflow.com/search?tab=votes&q=html%20textview

Dozens of comments or answers link to other questions asked, some even directly link to other posts with links. A huge mess to navigate through.

I personally would clean up but it would need a few more duplicate votes and I don't know if this is the right move at all and which ancestor to choose. Also the answers need some clean up aswell, old link only answers with dead links are pretty much useless.